# Variable routing express issue

Tags: node.js, express

I'm developing a SFTP Dashboard with nodeJS and express. 
But I have an issue with my root.

I want to navigate in each folders and subfolder and subsubfolders ... but my 
GET didn't work

URL : /home 
folder1 | folder2 | folder3

I click on Folders1, URL : /home/folders1
folder1-1 | folder1-2 ...

Next URL : /home/folders1/folder1-2

I made this route :

```
.get('/home/:file(.+)', function(req, res){

   conn.sftp(function(err, sftp){
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log('SFTP connexion ok')
    console.log(req.params.file)

    sftp.readdir('/'+ req.params.file, function(err, list) {
        if (err) throw err;

        var foldersList = []; 
        var filesList = [];

        list.forEach(function(value, key){
            if(value.longname.substring(0,1) == 'd'){
                foldersList.push(value)
            }
        })
        list.forEach(function(value, key){
            if(value.longname.substring(0,1) != 'd'){
                filesList.push(value)
            }
        })
        res.render('folders.ejs', { foldersList : foldersList, filesList : filesList, path : req.path })
    })
})})
```

But when I click on /home/folder1 :

> Cannot GET /home/files2

Can you help me please ?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem in your route parameter. Try using this.

```
.get(/\/home\/([file].+)/, function(req, res){
```

And for getting it you can use

```
req.params[0]
```

Comment: Thank you I'm entering in the GET.
But how I can get the param now ":file" please ?

Comment: @TzanaOverflow Fixed the regex and added the way you can get the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I tried :

```
 .get('/home\/:file([a-zA-Z.0-9-\/_!]+)', function(req, res){
```

It's working better, I can navigate in a lot of folders but I miss some caract, for exemple "éèö etc..."
Is it possible to inverse this regex to take all ?

thx